# C# Edit existing excel file and save to another place with NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I'm using NPOI in my .net5 console application.
My project SDK and NPOI package I installed:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetCore.NPOI" Version="1.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWorkbook wb = null;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Account.xlsx",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
            {
                wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
            }

            ISheet sht = wb.CreateSheet("test");
            sht.CreateRow(0).CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(0);

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Test.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                wb.Write(fs);
            }
        }
```

I got a 0KB excel file 'Test.xlsx' which is not able to be opened.